# Question about terminology, finite fields

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields

My English is not very good, and that's why I would really appreciate it if you could explain to me what the phrase : these elements are under the same domain under
$F$ and $\alpha$ means in this article:  http://www.pagewizardgames.com/finitefields_primeorder_danielpage.pdf.

Could you help me with that?

By the way, do you know a fairly simple proof of the theorem stating that for any integers $m, \ n, \ r > 1$, there exists a finite group $G$ with elements $a$ and $b$ such that $a$ has order $m$, $b$ has order $n$, and $ab$ has order $r$?

Comment: Your second question should be asked separately (I think it is already somewhere on the site though).

Comment: Ok, I'll try looking for it. What about the first one?

Comment: The linked document employs neither standard mathematical language nor rigorous mathematical proof. Instead, see any Abstract Algebra textbook for a proof of Cauchy's Theorem.

Comment: I think the construction answering the second question uses contrived $\operatorname{SL}$ groups.

Comment: Yes, I've just found it. It's here: http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GT310.pdf page 28. Do you think you could answer one question I have about the proof?

Comment: Namely, how do we know that if $p$ be a prime number not dividing $2mnr$, $p$ is a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/2mnr \mathbb{Z}$, and $q=p^k, \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$ is the ring's identity, then $2mnr$ divides $q -1$ and there exist elements $a, \ b, \ c$ with orders $2m, \ 2n, 2r$

Comment: I've already posted it as a new question. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371851/ring-mathbbz-2mnr-mathbbz-unit-identity-orders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am finding the linked page a little hard to read myself. Without reading more intensely to make sure, I have the feeling the author is not very clear on the topic.

At any rate, if you want a proof that finite fields have prime power orders, there are much clearer and simpler explanations than that, such as this question:

[Order of finite fields is $p^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72856/order-of-finite-fields-is-pn)