# Finite fields and cardinality

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

I am trying to get my head around the proof of the following:

Suppose K is a finite field. With $p=charK, |K|=p^r$ where r is a positive integer.

I am supplied with the following proof:

[image]

I do not understand how this proves what we are required to prove and I;m not satisfied with the last paragraph, can anyone offer some explanation?

Comment: Have you searched the site? This question/theme has appeared many, many times. One of the oldest incarnations is [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72856/11619).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $F$ is a subfield of $K$ then $K$ is an $F$-vector space. In the finite case, $r:=\dim_F K$ is certainly finite, which makes $K\cong F^r$.
Now $\operatorname{char}K=p$ means precisely that $K$ contains a subfield $F$ of cardinality $p$. Hence  $|K|=|F|^r=p^r$.