# Is my proof that finite fields have order $p^n$ valid?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, field-theory, finite-fields

Theorem: Every finite field has order $p^n$.

Proof:

Assume by contradiction a field $F$ of order $k$ such that $k$ has two distinct primes (of orders $m$ and $n$ dividing it), namely $p$ and $q$. Since $<F, +>$ is an (abelian) group of order k, we have a Sylow $p$-subgroup of order $p^m$. By Cauchy's theorem (existence of an element of prime order if it divides the group order) we have an element of order $p$ in the subgroup, hence in the group. i.e., $a +_p a = 0$ (where $+_p$ is addition to itself p times). The same logic with another distinct prime gives $b +_q b = 0$. WLOG take $p < q$

Consider $c \in F$ such that $c*a=b$ (field multiplication). This exists because $F/\{0\}$ possesses group structure. Then do $c(a +_p a) = c*0=0$ since the zero element of a field "absorbs multiplicatively". But then the LHS becomes $(b +_p b) = 0$ by distributivity and the construction of the element $c$. This implies that $b$ is of order $p$, which it cannot be because it was constructed to be within a Sylow $q$-subgroup and $p$, being different from $q$, can divide no power of $q$, so $b$ being of order $p$ contradicts Cauchy's theorem.

Therein lies the problem (as I see it) with a field with order not a prime power.

Comment: "Addition to itself $p$ times" is more commonly referred to as "multiply by $p$". And it doesn't matter whether you mean $p\in \Bbb Z$, or the representation of $p$ in your ring (in other words, the integer $p$ multiplied with the unit in the ring).

Comment: The proof may be valid, but it is unnecessarily complicated, because we can do without Cauchy and without Sylow, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72856/order-of-finite-fields-is-pn). But indeed, your proof is just along the same lines as the one by "caffeinemachine" at the duplicate.

Comment: IMO, the proof of the Sylow theorem is stronger than the result you are trying to prove and the argument is circular.

Comment: You're right, in fact there was absolutely no need to invoke Sylow's theorem and I have no idea why I did it. If using Cauchy is considered a good approach, I'm satisfied as it looks like my proof is solid if I just ctrl+F+deleted all references to Sylow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof looks right, but I don't understand why you felt the need of using Sylow's theorems. Why did you not apply Cauchy's theorem directly to $(F,+)$?

There are some problems concerning your notation. You should have written $F\setminus\{0\}$ instead of $F/\{0\}$. And I don't think that there is a need of introducing the $+_p$ notation. You could have just written $pa$ instead $a+_pa$.

Comment: Sorry about the set difference mistake (its kinda late). You're right, there was no need to appeal to Sylow's theorem, and I have no excuse for that. I used my weird notation because I sometimes confuse $pa$ with left-multiplication (I am not a fully fledged algebraist). With this, is using Cauchy's theorem a satisfactory and complete approach? (i.e. I did not leave a gap such that my result is either flawed or weaker)

Comment: I saw no gap in the proof. You could avoid the use of Cauchy's theorem. Since the field has order $p^mq^n$, you know that $p^mq^n1=0$ and therefore $p.(p^{n-1}q^m.1)=0$.

Comment: @MarcusAurelius Even avoiding $pa$, the standard notation for what you wanted would have been $\sum_{i=1}^pa$. The notation $a+_p a$ is not only non-standard, it's also just not very good. It suggests that something like $a+_p b$ is possible, and just becomes unwieldy if $a$ was a more involved expression (which would then need to be duplicated).