# Why does the cardinality of the vector space over a finite field of characteristic $p$ have to be a power of $p$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, finite-fields, positive-characteristic

In a lecture note that I have, it is written that

> if $F$ is a field of $q$ elements of characteristic $p$, then $q =
>  p^m$ for some $m>0$.
>
> To show this, observe that $F$ is a vector space over the field  $F_p
>  = \{n \cdot 1_F | n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ with $(n \cdot 1_F) * x = n \cdot x$ for $x\in F$.  So the result directly follows.

I can't understand why the cardinality of the vector space over a finite field of characteristic $p$ has to be a power of $p$.

Comment: Take a basis and start counting linear combinations.

Comment: @Randall Well,.. actually I couldn't find a basis.

Comment: You don't need to find a basis. You just need to know one exists.

Comment: @Randall But then, I should also need to know the size of the basis.

Comment: No you don't..  Call it $m$....  ("for **some** $m$....")

Comment: Sorely tempted to close this as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72856/11619). One of the most common questions about finite fields on our site :-(

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I actually search for the question, but apparently google failed me (I know from expericen that in site search is worst than google. )

Comment: Google cannot grok TeX. Neither can the local search. But a local search within the tag [tag:finite-fields] gave me a lot of hits in response to a few appropriate keywords (*cardinality* IIRC). Occasionally you absolutely need to search for a TeX-string. [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/) often helps there, but may need a bit of fine-tuning.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Actually, I tried Approach0 many times before, but wasn't successful, so I stop trying, but I will try next time; thanks.

Comment: Best of luck. Yes, we could use a better search engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose $F$ has basis $\{v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_m\}$ over $\mathbb{F}_p$.  Then each element $x$ of $F$ is **uniquely expressible** as
$$
x = c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 + \cdots +c_mv_m.
$$
But there are $p=|\mathbb{F}_p|$ choices for $c_1$, $p=|\mathbb{F}_p|$ choices for $c_2$, ..., and $p=|\mathbb{F}_p|$ choices for $c_m$.  Hence there are $p^m$ ways to build such linear combinations, so there are $p^m$ elements in $F$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.