# Why does $p$ have to be prime on a finite field $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$?

Tags: finite-fields

Why does $p$ have to be prime on a finite field $\{0,1,...,p-1\}$?

I'm looking at content on elliptic curve cryptography, and the guy brings up finite fields from $0$ to $p-1$ where $p$ is prime.

Why is $p$ prime? What's the reasoning behind this?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72856

Comment: If $n=a\cdot b$, where $a,b\not\in\{1,n\}$, then $a\cdot b\equiv 0\bmod n$; that shows $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ is not a field