# If $F$ is a finite field then $|F|=p^n$ for prime $p$ and some integer $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

I need some help proving the following:

If $F$ is a finite field then $|F|=p^n$ for prime $p$ and some integer $n$.

By contradiction, suppose $|F| =pq$ for primes $p$ and $q$. Then by Cauchy's theorem there exists $a, b\in F$ such that the order of $a$ is $p$ and the order of $b$ is $q$. I am not quite sure where to go from here, but I think we need to contradict that $F$ is a finite field. The only thing that comes to mind is to show zero-divisors.

1. Where can I go from here?
2. I thought every finite field had to have prime order? $p^n$ is not prime!

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: No, not every finite field has prime order. They all have prime power order.

Comment: Yes it does have to do with zero divisors. Let $p>0$ be the additive order of 1. If $p=rs$ is not prime, say for example $p=6$, then you get $(1+1)(1+1+1)=0$, contradiction. So $p$ is prime, and then all elements of the field must have additive order $p$.

Comment: I really like Amr's proof here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/463954/a-field-with-finitely-many-elements

Answer (score 3):

Think of $F$ as a vector space over its smallest subfield containing $1$ (which must be ...?).

Comment: That hat does fit anon's avatar very well! May be a pixel or two to thr right, but... :-)