# How to prove that order of a field is a power of its characteristic?

Tags: finite-fields

How to prove that order of a field $\mathbb{GF}(q)$ is a power of its characteristic $\lambda$?

What I can say is that every field has a subfield of order $\lambda$ if it helps

Comment: Your last sentence does help (+1 for that). But this question has already been answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53877/11619) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72856/11619), so I vote for this question being a duplicate (or to be merged). +1 to the correct answers by relatively new members here, of course.

Answer (score 4):

Hint 1: call $K$ the subfield of order $\lambda$. Then $\mathbb{GF}(q)$ becomes a vector space over $K$. 
Hint 2: if $x_1,\dots,x_m$ is a basis, every element can be written uniquely as $\sum_{i=1}^m\alpha_i x_i$ with $\alpha_i\in K$. How many $m$-uples $(\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_m)$ are there?

Comment: Thanks. I am a beginner. It takes time for me to see what you mean.  It would be better if you answered it completely but thank you again

Comment: @MahdiKhosravi , carizio *did answer* completely your question. That he didn't write down the explicit answer is because you **must** do some work on your own question...BTW, + 1

Answer (score 2):

${\mathbb{GF}}(q)$ is a vectorspace over ${\mathbb{GF}}(\lambda)$ [follows trivially from the definition of vectorspace]. Therefore it is, as a vectorspace, isomorphic to ${\mathbb{GF}}(\lambda)^d$ for some $d$ [by picking a basis]. So it has $\lambda^d$ elements.