# Why is $[\mathbb{F}_{p^n}:\mathbb{F}_{p}] = n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory

Let $p$ be a prime number. I know that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ is a finite field with $p^n$ Elements, which is the splitting field for $x^{p^n}-x$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. I also know that the extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_{p}$ is normal and separable, and hence Galois.

What I dont see is why its degree is n.

Comment: This is more or less unrelated to any of the rest of what you write. It is a vector space over $\mathbb{F}_p$ with $p^n$ elements, hence it has dimension $n$.

Comment: I believe the answers to [this old question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/53877/11619) address your question also. Not closing this as a duplicate without a second opinion though. In other words, this is at a simpler level than e.g. normality that you already figured out. (+1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $d$ be the dimension of $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$. Then, you have an isomorphism as vector spaces:
$$\mathbb{F}_{p^n} \cong \mathbb{F}_{p}^d$$
The cardinality of the first one is $p^n$, while the cardinality of the second one is $p^d$. Hence $d=n$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now I am very much ashamed of myself for not seeing this. :/ :)

Comment: @Miriam : you're welcome. And I think that you shouldn't be ashamed at all :-)