# Elementary proof that there is no field with 6 elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, alternative-proof

I am a T.A at an introductory linear algebra course this semester, and before getting into vector spaces, we give them some basic examples and properties of fields. Since this is a first semester course, everything is very elementary and we do not have too many tools.

I'd be happy to give them some elementary proof that there is no field of size $6$ (or some other small, concrete number, like 10... I just do not really care about the general case). They already know that $\mathbb Z _6$ is not a field, but I want to show that there is no other possible field of this size.

By elementary, I mean something which can be taught to math students on the second week to their first semester (so no arguments using groups and such). I can start talking about characteristics of fields and then show that the size has to be some power of the characteristic, but I'd prefer not to get into all of this. I am simply wondering if anyone here knows of an elementary proof for some concrete size (like $6$).

Thank in advance!

Comment: Isn't it pretty easy to show the characteristic must be prime if the field is finite?  Then just take the contrapositive.  I can't think of a simpler way.

Comment: @Randall doesn't that just show that the characteristic is 2 or 3? To get prime power you need that $F$ is a vector space over the prime field, which is not 2nd week.

Comment: I guess I'm thinking about excluding $\mathbb{Z}_6$ but I guess you're right:  I don't see how that excludes all other comm rings of order $6$.....

Comment: Ah, this question is really bothering me now.  Thanks...  (+1)

Comment: Let $F$ be a field of order $6$. Then $F$ has characteristic $p$ for some prime $p$. Since there are six elements, $n\cdot 1=m\cdot 1$ for some $1<n<m<6$, and so $p=2,3,5$. For $a\neq 0$, $a,2a,3a,4a,\dots,(p-1)a$ are all distinct. This partitions $F\setminus\{0\}$ into sets of size $p-1$. This eliminates $p=3,5$, so $p=2$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I do not really want to get into characteristics since my purpose is not the really teach them field theory (this is for a future course), but just give them a taste via little exercises. So I was hoping that for some concrete, small field, there is some clever argument which goes around that.

Comment: Well, you don't actually need it for what I have so far. You just need that $n\cdot 1=0$ for some smallest $n$, and then the argument above proves $n=2$ or $n=6$. $n=6$ gives $2\cdot3=0$, so that's out.

Comment: To get rid of 2, argue as follows: let $x\in F\setminus\{0,1\}$. Then $x\neq x+1$, because else $1=0$ by cancellation. This gives us four elements. There is another one left over, $y$. Now all of $y,y+1,y+x$ and $y+x+1$ must be distinct as otherwise two of $1,0,x$ and $x+1$ would be equal. Depending on how you set it up, that should be enough to show that if $1+1=0$, in fact every $F$ has $2$-power size.

Comment: Do the students know that the order of an element in a group (yes group) divides the order of the group?

Comment: @paw88789 no, they basically know nothing but the basics definitions and properties of fields

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53877/11619) (lest somebody feels like repeating that).

Comment: Assuming Lagrange's theorem from a first course on groups and subgroups has been covered, my suggestion may also work for your students. Don't get me wrong, I also endorse David's answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $F$ be a field with six elements. Since $|F|=6$, the sequence $0$, $1$, $1+1$, $1+1+1$, ..., $6\times 1$ must have a repetition. If $n\times 1=m\times 1$ for $n>m$, then by subtraction we obtain $(n-m)\times 1=0$. Thus the first repetition must actually be $n\times 1=0$ in the list above for some $2\leq n\leq 6$.

If $n\times 1=0$, then $n\times a=0$ for all $a\in F$, and similarly if $m\times a=0$ for some $a\neq 0$ then $m\times 1=0$ by dividing by $a$. This shows that for any $a$, $a$, $a+a$, ..., $(n-1)\times a$ are all distinct.

(This idea is due to Eric Wofsey in the comments below). If $n>2$ then $a+a\neq 0$ for any $a\neq 0$, as we have seen above. This shows that $a\neq -a$ for all non-zero $a$. Thus, pairing $a$ with $-a$ for all $a\in F\setminus\{0\}$, we see that $|F\setminus\{0\}|$ is even. This contradiction means that $n=2$.

Thus $n=2$. Let $a\in F\setminus\{0,1\}$, and notice that $0,1,a,a+1$ are all distinct. (If $a+1=0$ then $a=1$, if $a+1=a$ then $1=0$, if $a+1=1$ then $a=0$.) Notice that adding $1$ moves the elements $\{0,1,a,a+1\}$ around. If $b\in F\setminus\{0,1,a,a+1\}$ then $F$ must be
$$F=\{0,1,a,a+1,b,b+1\}.$$

Where is $a+b$? It cannot equal $0$ ($a=b$), it cannot equal $1$ ($a=b+1$), or $a$ ($b=0$) or $b$ ($a=0$), or $a+1$ ($b=1$) or $b+1$ ($a=1$). (All of these are by cancellation.) So $a+b\not\in F$, a contradiction.

Comment: More justification is needed in the $n=5$ and $n=3$ cases.  For instance, when $n=5$, it's not obvious why $a+a$ couldn't be a multiple of $1$.  (The quickest way is probably to multiply by $3$ to see that would imply $a$ is a multiple of $1$.  Alternatively, instead of looking at $a+a$, you could look at $a+1$.)

Comment: @EricWofsey In fact, the best way to proceed is to mimic the $n=2$ case and show directly, as that does essentially, that only powers of $n$ are allowed. Choose $a$ not in the collection you have so far built up. Then $i\times a+b$, where $b$ is in the collection and $i\in \{1,\dots,n-1\}$, are all distinct and not contained in the original set.

Comment: Alternatively, a faster way to rule out $n>2$ is just to note that if $1+1\neq 0$ then no nonzero element is its additive inverse so pairing the nonzero elements with their additive inverses shows there must be an even number of nonzero elements.

Comment: @EricWofsey yes, the standard proof that there's an odd number of elements of order $2$ in a group of even order. It's been incorporated (with accreditation) into the answer.

Comment: This is a very neat and elementary proof, exactly what I wanted :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

A modification of David Craven's fine answer.

Assume that such a field $F$ exists. Its multiplicative group has order five. Therefore (Lagrange) $F$ cannot have an element of multiplicative order two. In other words, we must have $-1=1$ implying that every element of $F$ is its own additive inverse.

Let $a\in F$ be distinct from $0$ and $1$. We know that $a+a=0$ and that $a+1$ is distinct from all of $0,1,a$. It follows that $\{0,1,a,a+1\}$ is an additive group. The remaining detail is that $a+(a+1)=(a+a)+1=0+1=1$. But, again by Lagrange, the group $(F,+)$ cannot have a subgroup of order four.

Comment: This is the best one. Slick!

Answer (score 1):

Let F = {0, 1, -1, a, b, c}. All a, b and c must have unique multiplicative inverses, that is, they must be paired with eachother. There's only 3 elements therefore at least one does not have an inverse. You can fairly easily generalise this to even numbers perhaps? Sorry for lack of formalism, this is intended as a comment but my score isn't high enough

Edit: Thank you in comments for pointing out my grave error and thank you for the insights I think I actually have a proof now though I could be wrong again. As said below in comments, the above proves this for the case $1 \neq -1$ so lets consider the case $1=-1$ and take $F = \{0, 1, a_1, a_2, a_3, a_4\}$ to be a field for such a case.

Because of the existence of the multiplicative inverse, we know that the inverse of $a_1$ must be one of $a_2, a_3, a_4$. Let's pick one arbitrarily, say $a_3$, and consequently $a_2$ must be the inverse of $a_4$. Thus we have:

$a_1^{-1} = a_3$,

$a_2^{-1} = a_4$.

Now let's look at $a_1 a_4$. It is certain that $a_1 a_4 \neq a_1$ or $a_1 a_4 \neq a_4$ since that implies $a_4 = 1$ or $a_1 = 1$ which violates uniqueness of identity. Similarly, $a_1 a_4 \neq 0$ or $a_1 a_4 \neq 1$ since that would contradict uniqueness of zero element and inverse respectively. This means that $a_1 a_4 = a_2 \space or \space a_3$. It doesn't matter which one we pick, the proof is pretty much the same for both from here on out, so lets pick $a_1 a_4 = a_3$. From this equality and using a tad of manipulation:

$a_2 = a_1^2$

Because of the existence of the additive inverse, the inverse of $a_1$ must be one of $-a_2, -a_3, -a_4$. These 3 cases are considered briefly as follows (using $1 = -1$):

1.) $a_1 = -a_2 = a_2 = a_1^2$ which implies $a_1 = 1$

2.) $a_1 = -a_3 = a_3 = a_1^{-1}$ which implies $a_2 = a_1^2 = 1$

3.) $a_1 = -a_4 = a_2 = a_1^2$ which implies $a_1 = 1$

This contradicts uniqueness of multiplicative identity. Furthermore, since choices above were arbitrary and/or near identical, we are forced to conclude that F is not in fact a field.

I don't know if this is the right kinda proof for you as its a tad long but should be understandable enough right?

Comment: This argument is not correct, since there are fields with an even number of elements (they all satisfy $1 = -1$).

Comment: Not correct perhaps but a great starting point. If we split into two cases: $1 = -1$ and $1 \neq -1$ then the above solves the second (nice, intuitive) case. Then examining the first case (which is a bizarre can of worms if you never have seen characteristic 2 fields before) is a GREAT way of exploring what the field axioms do and do not tell you, what the distributive property actually is etc. I think this can be a very fruitful approach.

Comment: Yeah, this might work because $x^2=1$ easily implies $x= \pm 1$, so everything else must have a "separate" inverse.  Definitely a good start.

Comment: Here is a good piece on what's so weird about characteristic 2 fields.  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1573308/whats-so-special-about-characteristic-2/1573310#1573310

Comment: Why can't $a_1$ be the additive inverse of $-a_1$?

Comment: "There's only 3 elements therefore at least one does not have an inverse." ... or is its own multiplicative inverse.  For instance $5$ is its own multiplicative inverse modulo $6$.

Comment: I don't think what you have shown can work as such. For there exists a field that contains elements $0,1,g,g^2,g^3,g^4$ and $g^5=1$, each of the listed elements is its own additive inverse. Multiplicative inverses come from the relation $g^5=1$. However, that field has no less than 16 elements because the sums of powers of $g$ must be included. What I'm getting at is that because of this, any argument that does not get into sums (like what is $a_1+a_1^2$?) is doomed  to fail. You are not really using the additive structure at all, because the case where $-x=x$ for all $x$ deals with that.